# Update to RC of WebApi causing Could not load type 'System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver' from assembly error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have recently upgraded to the RC versions of the WebApi using Nuget but am now getting the following error.

> Could not load type 'System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver'
>   from assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Using the object browser, I can see the correct reference is in there. I have tried rebuilding, cleaning and clearing the temporary internet files.

A google search turned up http://forums.asp.net/t/1810546.aspx/1?Dependency+Resolver+throws+an+error+with+Unity but this wasn't much help.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

[image: Screenshot from Visual Studio]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer in the end was that MVC 4 was conflicting, I assume that the dlls it put in the GAC were taking precedence, uninstalling MVC 4 fixed the problem for me.